# Editar arquivo de configuração

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Tenho um arquivo de configuração com diversos parâmetros, exemplo:

```
campo1=valor
campo2=valor
campo3=
```

Gostaria de atribuir um valor ao `campo3` com Shell Script.
Tentei fazer com `awk` mas não consegui.

O valor a ser substituído vou ter em uma variável.

Comment: `echo "campo3=$valorDaSuaVariavel" >> seuArquivo.txt`

Comment: Isso vai fazer com que o campo3 seja inserido no final do arquivo, quero substituir o valor do que já existe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `awk` com a opção `-F`, que indica qual caractere será usado para separar o campo do valor em cada linha. No caso, usarei `=`, para separar o nome do campo do seu valor.

Depois basta comparar o nome do campo e fazer a substituição de acordo com o que você precisa. O script ficaria assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
valor=$1
arquivo=$2
awk -F'=' '{if ($1 == "campo3") { print $1 "=" ENVIRON["valor"] } else { print $1 "=" $2}}' $arquivo
```

Ou seja, se o nome do campo for `campo3`, escreve o novo valor, senão escreve os valores que já têm.

O script recebe dois parâmetros: o valor a ser colocado no `campo3` e o nome do arquivo a ser lido. Atribuí os parâmetros do script em variáveis com nomes mais claros, para eles não serem confundidos com os campos `$1` e `$2` do `awk` (no caso, dentro do `awk`, `$1` é o nome do campo e `$2` é o seu valor).

Por exemplo, se o nome do script for `trocaval.sh`, basta rodar:

```
trocaval.sh novo_valor arquivo.config
```

A saída será:

```
campo1=valor
campo2=valor
campo3=novo_valor
```

Se quiser jogar a saída para um novo arquivo, use `>` para redirecionar a saída:

```
trocaval.sh novo_valor arquivo.config > novo_arquivo.config
```

Não recomendo redirecionar a saída para o mesmo arquivo, pois este pode ser sobrescrito e você perderá seu conteúdo. É mais garantido escrever primeiro em um novo arquivo, e se for o caso, renomeá-lo:

```
mv novo_arquivo.config arquivo.config
```

Se quiser, pode colocar tudo isso dentro do script também:

```
#!/bin/bash
valor=$1
arquivo=$2

# joga a saída do awk em um novo arquivo
awk .... > novo_arquivo
# renomeia o novo_arquivo para o nome do arquivo original
mv novo_arquivo $arquivo
```